# No such file or directory ERROR. Part of pathname is exported in .bash_profile

Tags: export, bash, nosuchfileexception

Inside a script I have named `monitor power` I have a variable named `CHARGE_CYCLES`:

> `CHARGE_CYCLES="$TOOLS/Data/Charge\ Cycles.txt"`

The variable `$TOOLS` is declared and exported in my `.bash_profile` because I want it to be available to various scripts:

> `TOOLS=/Users/sl/.Tools`
>   `export TOOLS`

I have a line in `monitor power` that uses the variable `CHARGE_CYCLES`:

> `cat "$CHARGE_CYCLES"`

However, upon running the script I get the error:

> `/Users/sl/.Tools/Data/Charge\ Cycles.txt: No such file or directory`

The annoying thing is that this file DOES exist in this exact spot. Spelling, capitalization, everything is exactly the same. So I'm thinking it has something to do with exporting `TOOLS` from `.bash_profile` but I don't see why because the error prints the exact pathname I wanted, it just says it doesn't exist.

I'm new to this stuff, so I don't really know what's going on here! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Filenames with leading/trailing/embedded whitespace are a pain in the butt to deal with in shell scripts.  You are lucky to learn this lesson early in your career!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to escape the space character when defining `CHARGE_CYCLES`.

Comment: Yeah you're right I didn't even notice that. Thanks!